# Hot holding brisket elote/cream corn

Tags: food-safety, food-science

So we serve on our food truck a awesome brisket elote cup creamed corn with a Mayo/sour cream base. On the truck we smoke the corn put a dollop of the dressing in the bottom of the cup top that with corn and then cheese and brisket easy. But with large catering events and wanting to serve it any idea or thoughts on hot holding? Thanks so much